# Identify this part?

Tags: part-identification

Someone at my house *apparently* found it under my car. I have no idea what it is.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I cannot tell you *exactly* what it is, but I can tell you with 100% surety ***it doesn't belong on your Hyundai***. It looks as though it is a line piercer used in some plumbing operations. The larger screw on the bottom pushes a line up in the curved section, then the top portion is a valve.

Comment: That is correct. It is a C-Clamp style saddle valve used for plumbing. http://www.lasco.net/saddle-valve-c-2937_1461_1468_1470/c-clamp-14-saddle-valve-p-12305.html#.WRBurze1uUk

Comment: Thanks for the post. Cooter Davenport says it's illegal in most states. Is that correct?

Comment: Since this isn't a car part, it really doesn't matter for this SE. I'd suggest you ask that question on DIY.SE ... I've seen ones like it used, so I don't know the validity of his statement.

Answer (score 2):

It is a water line piercing (saddle) valve. They are illegal in most states.

Do I get a cookie?

Comment: Just curious. Why are they illegal? What can I do with these?

Comment: "Illegal" as in Illegal to possess or just not compliant with most building codes?

Comment: Illegal for a licensed plumber to use, or to use in a commercial building.  So, not compliant with codes.  You're not going to get busted for illegal pipe-tapping paraphernalia.

Comment: @JPhi1618 One would hope not, but there are stranger laws than this in the US.